# What is an example of a non-formal $A_\infty$ algebra over a discrete ring?

Tags: higher-algebra

For an $A_\infty$ algebra (say I do everything over $\mathbb{Q}$) modeled by dg-algebras I can understand the definition of formality (that its homology groups is equivalent in a $A_\infty$ way to the original algebra). I imagine that this definition also extends to the Lurie/spectra setting? As in take homotopy groups and ask whether the algebra I get is isomorphic to the original one as an $E_1$-algebra. So with all this in mind, let me ask a very basic question. What is an example of a non-formal $A_\infty$ algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$/a discrete ring?

Comment: Isn’t such an isomorphism impossible even on the level of spectra, forgetting the multiplication, once a single $k$-invariant is nonzero? So e.g. the sphere spectrum or the K-theory spectrum.

Comment: I guess I want to know if it can be bad over $\mathbb{Q}$ or a discrete ring? of course there are spectra that are not modeled by discrete things. I've edited to match this opionion. Maybe it is just fine actually over a discrete ring and we don't have non-formality, sorry I don't really know this stuff. Like for E_n we should have nonformality easily over a discrete ring but for E_1 I'm not sure if there is any reason that nonformality should occur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyone with a non-trivial Massey product, e.g. the rational cochain algebra of the complement of the Borromean rings in $S^3$. Presented in this way, it is strictly associative. If you take a minimal model, the ternary operation $m_3$ can't be trivial because it represents triple Massey products.